# A priori estimates for almost similar similar pde's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a sufficiently smooth domain. Let the semi-linear pde problem
\begin{align}
u_t-\Delta u &= f(u),\;\;\;on\;\;\;\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2\\
\nabla u\cdot n & = 0\;\;\;on\;\;\; \partial\Omega.
\end{align}
Let that we have some a priori estimates for the solution of a pde problem, such that
\begin{equation}
\|u(t)\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq C,
\end{equation}
where the constant $C$ depends only on problem data. Let now, the following semi-linear pde problem
\begin{align}
v_t-\Delta v + v &= f(v),\;\;\;on\;\;\;\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2\\
\nabla v\cdot n & = 0\;\;\;on\;\;\; \partial\Omega.
\end{align}
Is there any connection between the apriori estimates for the above semi-linear pde problems? In fact, can I immediately conclude to
\begin{equation}
\|v(t)\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq C,
\end{equation}
where the constant $C$ depends only on problem data?